# Akka. Is there a way to share code between two receives?

Tags: scala, akka

Let's say I have several receives and use become() unbecome() to switch between them. And all receives have some common message handling. Like this:

```
class Test extends Actor {

  override def receive: Receive = first

  def first: Receive = {
    case "common" => // how to share?
      println("common stuff")
    case "second" =>
      println("move to second")
      context.become(second)
  }

  def second: Receive = {
    case "common" =>  // how to share?
      println("common stuff")
    case "first" =>
      println("move to first")
      context.become(first)
  }

}
```

Right now I see two ways:

- Duplicate pattern match on "common" and
  handle it in some function like handleCommon()
- Merge receives like
  this, but it doesn't seem right to me.

Here is an example of the second one:

```
class Test extends Actor {

      override def receive: Receive = merge(common, first)

      def common: Receive = {
        case "common" =>
          println("common stuff")
      }

      def first: Receive = {
        case "second" =>
          println("move to second")
          context.become(merge(common, second))
      }

      def second: Receive = {
        case "first" =>
          println("move to first")
          context.become(merge(common, first))
      }

      private def merge(functions: Receive*): Receive = {
        case any =>
          val fOpt = functions find (_.isDefinedAt(any))
          if (fOpt.isDefined) {
            fOpt foreach (f => f(any))
          } else {
            unhandled(any)
          }
      }
    }
```

I'm sure there have to be a better way to do this. Is there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `orElse`:

```
def common: Receive = {
  case "common" =>
    println("common stuff")
}

def first: Receive = ({
  case "second" =>
    println("move to second")
    context.become(second)
}: Receive) orElse common

def second: Receive = ({
  case "first" =>
    println("move to first")
    context.become(first)
}: Receive) orElse common
```

Note that you have to explicitly annotate the type at the end of the expression because otherwise scala will infer `Function1` and not `Receive`.

Comment: I guess it's better to define `common` with `val` to make it easier to see it's just a PartialFunction only for mix-in

Comment: I don't think it matters too much, in the end even if it's a val it's a function so it's evaluated at each call anyway, usually I make this kind of shared receives private.

Comment: That's exactly what I was trying to edit my comment. I wanted to say `private val` instead of `val` .